# Redirecting to Login page in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I am working on OTRS where i want to set OTRS Login page on otrs.mydomain.com.
I am having machine CentOS release 6.2 (Final).

Currently I am accessing it,using otrs.mydomain.com/otrs/customer.pl for customer login
AND otrs.mydomain.com/otrs/index.pl for admin login.

I changed DocumentRoot to /opt/otrs but its not working as it should.

OTRS is installed in /opt/otrs/
I am using Apache Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix).  Now i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a soft link in in your html folder for /opt/otrs. And use that as the document root. Generally Apache doesnt work properly in other folders. Incase if you still want to use the opt folder then you will have to change the group settings.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. but it didn't work out.

Comment: `Generally Apache doesnt work properly in other folders` is just not true. Generally You need to take care of permissions and adjusted config of apache, not more not less. And symlinks to not really change anything in regards to permission settings.